# Angular Routing Is not Loading page Even If I added template is also Not Showing

Tags: angularjs

Please Help me Here why i'm not able to Route
**app.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagement", ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!")
        $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "template/Home.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirect:"/Login"
        })
    }])
```

This is my Html code Here I defind my Navigation Buttons

```
<nav>
                <a href="/#/home">Home</a>
            </nav>
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had hash prefix `!` in routing, your `href` should have `!` in the URL right after `#`

```
href="#!/home"
```

Comment: @MDGosoddin Glad to help you, Thanks ;)